# span is returning empty whitespace

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to get the price and details of this [product](http://www.zara.com/us/en/man/shoes/leather/brown-braided-leather-ankle-boots-c0p4065286.html) with this code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Element productitem = doc.select("div.right-container._right-container").first();
Iterator<Element> price = productitem.select("div.price._product-price").iterator();
System.out.println(price.next().text());
that returns empty whitespace
```

also this:

```
Elements span = doc.select("span");
System.out.println(spanText);
for (Element e:span)
    System.out.println(e.text());
```

returns empty, everything but the price.

even just this:

```
Element productitem = doc.select("div.right-container._right-container").first();
System.out.println(productitem );
```

would return whole line `<span>69.90</span>` to `&nbsp;`
is there 's a reason why this span is visible on browser and not for Jsoup?

Comment: Can you share html also i could not find anything on the url

Comment: This is exactly the point on browser inspect element it exists in jsoup not visible

Comment: i am in different country it forcing to choice country and continue.

Comment: https://www.zara.com/in/en/man/shoes/leather/brown-braided-leather-ankle-boots-c0p4065286.html

Comment: @soorapadman or you can choose your country and continue

Comment: whenever i try to connect the url it showing home page only. I have print the html for above url  it showing only languges, country and Go nothing else. I believe along with a url we should set language and country to work properly.I believe something to do with  cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you checking html? By F12 or by view source? Because when I go to view source I can see there is no price in html:

```
<div class="price _product-price" tabindex="0">&nbsp;</div>
```

When I look into html by F12:

[image]

When I look into html by view-source:

[image]

So the result returned by Jsoup is right.

But when I'm looking for price in this file (for my country it's 199.00) I can find line like this:

```
"isBuyable":true,"price":19900,"tags"
```

Maybe you should try find the price this way.

Comment: look for this class price _product-price you'll find it

Comment: @KhalilM There is one entry of this class, this one which I posted in my answer. When you view the source in Elements after F12 there is span with price in this class. But when you click right button on page and choose view source you should see only the line that I posted above.

Comment: I added scrrenshots to my answer. It looks like Jsoup is looking for code like in view-source and you shouldn't suggest a F12 html.